# Memcache deleteMulti not working

Tags: php, caching, memcached, pecl

I have memcache 2.2.7 installed (using PECL on localhost) and currently using the PHP Memcache(d) class. I am trying to delete multiple keys in one function call using one of the documented methods:

simplified code:

```
$memcache = new \Memcache;
$memcache->deleteMulti($key_list);
```

However, I get an error:

```
"Call to undefined method Memcache::deleteMulti()"
```

The argument $key_list is an array of keynames as required. Does anyone know the reason for this? Has this method been recalled? Is it possible I am not actually using the Memcached class, but Memcache instead? How can I tell? If it is not possible to use this method, is there an alternative that will allow me to delete up to a few hundred keys at once, and do it FAST?

Answer (score 1):

The [Memcache](http://php.net/memcache) ext does not have **deleteMulti** method, this is the reason of this error.

You can use [Memcached](http://php.net/memcached):

```
$memcache = new \Memcached;
$memcache->deleteMulti($key_list);
```